# How to implement multiple files selection and upload using HttpFileCollectionBase in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented the multiple file selection using [PLUpload](http://www.plupload.com/) framework.

It is possible to get `Request.Files` in controller to be passed to model (there will process the files) ?

I know that `Request.Files` get automatically the all `input type='file'` tags from the page.

What workaround is necessary to do ?

I don't want to upload files before submitting form. I want when submit the form then the upload will proceed as such.

Example: After selecting two files, I have the following tags in HTML code:

```
<div id="filelist">
  <div id="p17lu3r33g14jk1dg31u0dg1l1lll3">test.xml (272 KB) <b></b></div>
  <div id="p17lu3r33h9mt2oiel81l5t17iq4">abcde.xml (272 KB) <b></b></div>
</div>
```

And the HTML code for uploader form:

```
<div id="upload-container">
   <div>
      <a id="pickfiles" href="#">Select files</a>      
      <a id="uploadfiles" href="#">Upload selected files</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div id="filelist">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, you can. gofor List<HTTPPostedFileBase>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the name of the file input is for example `files` you could have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ....
}
```

or define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(MyViewModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Once again it is important to have the file input named the same. For example:

```
<input type="file" name="files" />
<input type="file" name="files" />
<input type="file" name="files" />
...
```

---

UPDATE:

It appears that you want to use the `PLUpload` plugin. This plugin sends each file individually and uses chunks. So here's an example of how you could handle the upload on the server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(int? chunk, string name)
{
    var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
    var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    chunk = chunk ?? 0;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, name), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    return Json(new { message = "chunk uploaded", name = name });
}
```

Comment: Darin, using PLUpload I will have only `div`, no input ... that is my problem. See my edited question.

Comment: Oh, so you want to use Plupload? Alright, let me update my answer.

Comment: I have no inputs there, only div, see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand your last code, but I don't want to upload as ajax request. I want when press submit the form (which contains more fields not only the files) I want to upload the multiple selected files.

Comment: Then don't use PLUpload. The whole point of this plugin is to upload files asynchronously. If you want to upload multiple files in a standard fashion, then it could be as simple as having file inputs.

Comment: I got it, I will upload into temporary folder and move them (if data is ok) to correct folder. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26382/discussion-between-snake-eyes-and-darin-dimitrov)